# Blogger Emporio templete: Add second line of text on homepage snippets

Tags: templates, customization, blogger

My blog is https://testfnm.blogspot.com based on the Blogger Emporio template.

On the homepage, under the titles of the snippets, I would like to add a second line of text with the country name.

So for instance, under the title "Milford Sound" I would like to add the country name "New Zealand". Similarly, under Amsterdam, I would like to add Netherlands. And so on...

How do I do that please?

Comment: How about using the inbuilt `location` tag? You may add location manually.

Comment: Thanks for the message Severus. Unfortunately the locations only show up in an open Post, not on the homepage. I can set Labels to show up on the homepage snippets, but they show up only if you hover the cursor over the snippet. And on mobile you can't even see that because there is no cursor. I would like a solution that shows the location permanently on the snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to adding a second line of text to the snippets, I have found a method to make the Labels permanently visible on the snippets of the homepage. I have put only one label per post, the label being the country name. Thus against each snippet a label (the country name) is now visible both on desktop and mobile.

I used this CSS code to make the labels visible:

```
.labels-outer-container {opacity: 1 !important;}
body.feed-view .post-labels {display: inline-block;}
```

You can see how the results look here: https://www.firozemistry.com